# win32 c++ how to make a window resizable by dragging the sides but with no frame, or border

Tags: c++, winapi, x86

The only way I can have a window with no borders is by using no style, just using WS_POPUP. If I use WS_THICKFRAME I have the resize functionality but it adds a gray bar at the top (not the title bar, it is just a gray bar about 5px height).

This code here is supposed to show the sizing arrows but it is not working:

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:
{
            
    POINTS pt = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);

    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);

    if (pt.x >= rc.left && pt.x < rc.left + 5)
    {
        return HTLEFT;
    }
    else if (pt.x < rc.right && pt.x >= rc.right - 5)
    {
        return HTRIGHT;
    }
    else if (pt.y >= rc.top && pt.y < rc.top + 5)
    {
        return HTTOP;
    }
    else if (pt.y < rc.bottom && pt.y >= rc.bottom - 5)
    {
        return HTBOTTOM;
    }
    return HTCLIENT;
}
```

Comment: *How* is it not working?  What are the results of `MAKEPOINTS` and `GetWindowRect` when this function is called with the mouse in the correct position?.

Comment: if I add an message box before "return HTBOTTOM" for example It works, when the mouse is at the bottom it show the message box, but the mouse arrow doesn't change to resize arrow and if I drag nothing happends

Comment: Make sure you're passing all unhandled messages to `DefWindowProc`.

Comment: Try enabling WS_THICKFRAME and handling WM_NCCALCSIZE as a no-op (no non-client area), that should get rid of the visible frame. Also handle WM_SETCURSOR properly.

Comment: yeah with WS_TICKFRAME and VM_CACALSIZE returning 0 I get rid of the frame and I have resize functionality handling WM_NCHITTEST and returning HTLEFT HTRIGHT etc, but now every time I resize the window size increases about 10 px each side lol...